# ¿Como puedo restar los datos de un arreglo en java?

Tags: java, array, vscode

Estoy aprendiendo Java y debo de crear un arreglo de N números y con esos números debo de obtener la Suma Total, Producto Total y también la Resta Total, tanto la suma como el producto ya me salieron, pero la resta no, como puedo obtener el resultado de la resta, ejemplo mi arreglo será de 5 posiciones y los datos serán 3-4-10-2-7, la Suma es 26, el producto 1680 y la resta debería ser -20, pero mi código me imprime el resultado de la resta como -26, lo dejo a continuación

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a[], can, i, suma = 0, producto = 1, resta = 0;

    System.out.print("ingrese la cantidad de numeros que tendra el arreglo: ");
    can = entrada.nextInt();
    // pedimos los numeros a introducir en el arreglo
    a = new int[can];

    System.out.println("\nINGRESO DE DATOS\n");

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("Ingrese el valor de la posicion[" + i + "] = ");
        a[i] = entrada.nextInt();
       
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // se imrpime el arreglo
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Valor en la posicion[" + i + "] = ");
        System.out.print(a[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        suma = suma + a[i];
        producto = producto * a[i];

        resta = resta - a[i];
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("La suma total de los valores del arreglo es: " + suma);
    System.out.println("El producto total de los valores del arreglo es: " + producto);
    System.out.println("La diferencia total de los valores del arreglo es: " + resta);

}
```

Comment: La variable resta no puedes inicializarla con 0, sino con la primera posicion del arreglo, ej resta = arr[0];

Comment: Hola, la he inicializado de esta forma resta=a[0]; pero ahora me imprime que la resta es -23, como obtengo el -20 que me debería de dar la resta de todos los elementos (3)-(4)-(10)-(2)-(7)

Comment: Haz un ciclo for solo para la resta, y empieza ese ciclo en 1 no en 0, teniendo en cuenta lo que te dije anteriormente

Comment: Ya me ha salido el resultado correcto, muchas gracias mi estimado, llevaba horas con ese detalle, muchas gracias.